# Raster/predict function returns results lower than the training sample range

Tags: r, geospatial, random-forest, raster, geography

I am using the function 'predict' (Raster package) to classify cropland presence over a Landsat TOA layer. The classification model used is Random forest (regression). The training dependent variable has only two values: 0 and 1, in consequence, I expect to have predicted values inside the range [0, 1]. However I am getting negative values as predicted. Is this normal? or what I should I change?. Code below:

```
    ras <- brick("TOA_imagery_2018.tif");
    sam <- read.csv("sample.csv");
    sam$cropland[sam$cropland == 2] <- 0;
    type <- 'classification'  # 'regression', 'classification'
    if (type=='classification'){
       sam$cropland<-as.factor(sam$cropland) # else, nothing
    }
    mr <- randomForest(cropland ~ B1 + B2 + B3 + B4 + B5+ B6 + B7 + elevation + ndvi + evi, data = sam, ntree=100, type=type)
    cla <- predict(ras, mr, "result.tif")
```

Thank you for your any help

Comment: Yes, please share your data or subset, so we can try to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have minus values. Check the values in the cropland column to ensure they are all 0 or 1. If they are, you should make your data or a subset of your data available so it can be tested.

I would have posted this a comment but I don't have the rep.